# SQL GROUP BY/COUNT even if no results

Tags: sql, mysql

I am attempting to get the information from one table (games) and count the entries in another table (tickets) that correspond to each entry in the first.  I want each entry in the first table to be returned even if there aren't any entries in the second.  My query is as follows:

```
SELECT g.*, count(*) 
FROM games g, tickets t 
WHERE (t.game_number = g.game_number
   OR NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM tickets t2 WHERE t2.game_number=g.game_number))
GROUP BY t.game_number;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to do a left-join:

```
SELECT g.Game_Number, g.PutColumnsHere, count(t.Game_Number) 
FROM games g
LEFT JOIN tickets t ON g.Game_Number = t.Game_Number
GROUP BY g.Game_Number, g.PutColumnsHere
```

Alternatively, I think this is a little clearer with a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT g.Game_Number, G.PutColumnsHere,
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Tickets T WHERE t.Game_Number = g.Game_Number) Tickets_Count
FROM Games g
```

Just make sure you check the query plan to confirm that the optimizer interprets this well.

Comment: Thank you very much - I'm kind of embarrassed that I didn't realize this should have been a left join.

Comment: The subquery may look clearer for a non-set oriented thinker, but there may be some severe performance differences between the two methods. I'm not a MySQL expert, so I don't know for sure, but I would at least experiment with both before deciding.

Comment: @Tom: I agree with you. In some cases like this, the SQL Server optimizer will convert this to a more efficient left join with group by. As you say, though, you've got to check the query plans to make sure they're performing well.

Answer (score 2):

You need to learn more about how to use joins in SQL:

```
SELECT g.*, count(*) 
FROM games g
 LEFT OUTER JOIN tickets t 
 USING (game_number)
GROUP BY g.game_number;
```

Note that unlike some database brands, MySQL permits you to list many columns in the select-list even if you only GROUP BY their primary key.  As long as the columns in your select-list are *functionally dependent* on the GROUP BY column, the result is unambiguous.

Other brands of database (Microsoft, Firebird, etc.) give you an error if you list any columns in the select-list without including them in GROUP BY or in an aggregate function.

Answer (score 1):

"`FROM games g, tickets t`" is the problem line. This performs an inner join. Any where clause can't add on to this. I think you want a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`.

Comment: See Michael's response. (Ouch. Beaten by 21 seconds.)

Comment: That comma syntax actually performs a cartesian join, not an inner join.

Comment: Well an inner join is basically a cartesian join with a restriction (the `ON` clause)